# How do I diagram this sentence ("Boats docked at Toronto in Ontario should be registered with the town hall.")?

Tags: grammar

I need help breaking down this sentence, which I found in my grammar book.

> Boats docked at Toronto in Ontario should be registered with the town hall.

I'm assuming "docked" here functions as an adjective? And "at Toronto" and " in Ontario" are both prepositions? What is the function of "should be"? Is it acting as a helping verb?

Comment: Buzzer for that sentence. So, taking it apart is futile.

Comment: (S (NP (NP Boats)
       (SBAR (WHNP **that**)
             (S (VP **are**
                    (VP docked
                        (PP at
                            (NP Toronto))
                        (PP in
                            (NP Ontario)))))))
   (VP should
       (VP be
           (VP registered
               (PP with
                   (NP the town hall))))))

Comment: @Greybeard - I just had a stroke reading this...

Comment: @ Justin would be  helpful if you tell me what is the problem with the sentence. I actually got it directly from a grammar book. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: _Docked_ is a participle, part of a _Whiz_-reduced relative clause; @Greybeard kindly boldfaced the reduced parts in the parse above. There's nothing wrong with the sentence grammatically.

Comment: @ John, thank you very much. I was confused because, apparently, this sentence gave someone a stroke. Didn't seem that bad to me; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @skyfox009 - No, I had a stroke reading Greybeard's comment.. The sentence is fine, don't worry :)

Comment: This is not relevant to what the question is about, but the wording 'Toronto in Ontario', although not incorrect, is somewhat unusual; it would be more idiomatic to say just 'Toronto, Ontario,' or simply 'Toronto' (if the context makes it clear what the province is).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase, "docked at Toronto in Ontario," is a past participial phrase.  That phrase is adjectival in nature.  It modifies the head of the subject, "boats."

The phrase, "should be registered," is a verb phrase.  "Should" and "be" are auxiliary verbs, with "should" being a modal auxiliary verb (@user405662).  "Registered" is the main verb.

The phrase, "with the town hall," is a prepositional phrase.  It acts as an adverbial phrase, and modifies the main verb, "registered."

Comment: _should_ is a *modal auxiliary* to be precise.